# Is there a way to get intellisense for content inside imported partials in VS Code?

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a `styles.scss` and a partial that holds some color variables `_colors.scss`.

`_colors.scss`:

```
$primary: #009688;
$secondary: #4caf50;
```

`styles.scss`:

```
@import 'colors';

.blurred {
    color: $primary;
    filter: blur(2px);
}
```

This works, but I would like to be able to have intellisense for the `$primary` variable, just as if it was declared in `styles.scss`. Is there a feature/extension available for VS code that can do this?

Comment: Any reason for addition of Less tag?

Comment: Did not use less before but from knowledge it has partials too

Comment: Sort of yes but if you want your question to be about partials in general then maybe you should reword the question and make it generic. I've never worked with VS and there could be different solutions for Less and Sass.

Comment: The question is about partials. But 'css preprocessor partial' is not and will probably never be a tag.

Comment: I don't see the Q actually about *partials*. It's just about *any* imported (as in "included") Sass/Less code in a Less/Sass file respectively. (Technically that "partial" thing is quite akward in this context since we're about syntax highlighting thus the Sass/Less language in the end and the "partial" is solely a compiling tool feature).

Comment: I.e. just replace "partials" with "files" in the title and the should/should-not-be [less] problem is solved.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6734

Answer (score 6):

Install SCSS IntelliSense

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-scss

[image]

[Image source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6734#issuecomment-256049663)

There is no color preview though https://github.com/mrmlnc/vscode-scss/issues/13

because vscode doesn't support this yet and there is no plan to add it https://github.com/mrmlnc/vscode-scss/issues/29

Comment: Anything for full VS?